# Mean of normal CDF

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, normal-distribution

Question-

> Let $X$ follows $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$. Show that $\mathbb{E}(\Phi(X)) \neq \frac{1}{2}$ for any $\mu \neq 0$, where $\Phi(X)$ is the cdf of $N(0,1)$ distribution.

But the theorem of Probability Integral transformation says that cdf of any random variable follows $Uniform (0,1)$ distribution. So the normal cdf should not depend on $\mu$ and always follow  $Uniform (0,1)$ distribution with mean $\frac{1}{2}$.
Can you please point out what I am missing here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "cdf of any random variable follows Uniform(0,1) distribution" No, the result is that $F_Y(Y)$ is uniform on $(0,1)$ (if $Y$ is continuous). Here one is looking at $F_Y(X)$ for $X$ and $Y$ with different distributions.

Comment: And it happens that $$E(\Phi(X))=\Phi\left(-\frac\mu{\sqrt{1+\sigma^2}}\right)$$ hence indeed, $E(\Phi(X))=\frac12$ iff $\mu=0$.

Comment: Can you show the calculation please?

Comment: Start from the fact that, for every $x$, $$\Phi(x)=P(\mu+\sigma X_0\leqslant x)$$ with $X_0$ standard normal, hence, assuming that $X_0$ is independent of $X$, $$\Phi(X)=P(\mu+\sigma X_0\leqslant X\mid X)$$ Integrating, one gets $$E(\Phi(X))=P(\mu+\sigma X_0\leqslant X)=P(\sigma X_0-X\leqslant-\mu)=\cdots$$

Comment: But why $\Phi(X)=P(\mu+\sigma X_0\leq X| X)$ but not $P(\mu+\sigma X_0\leq X)$?

Comment: To begin with, because it is a random variable, not a real number.